# Identify number of times the values changes in a pandas column within time in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas dataframe has this:

```
name        startTime   endTime
AAA BBB         0           8.5
BBB CCC         9           15
AAA BBB         15          25
AAACCCC         25          60
XXXX YYYY       65          80
AAA BBB         80          90
BBB CCC         90          105
XXX YYYY        105         108
AAA BBB         108         120
```

I want to split by endTime (which is in secs) and count number of times the name changes within that block of 1 minute.
So my output should be

```
1st Min     4
2nd Min     5
```

Any help is appreaciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `//` to convert `endTime` to minutes:

```
# substract a very small amount so that 60 is first minute
minutes = (df['endTime']-1e-9)//60
df['name'].ne(df['name'].shift()).groupby(minutes).sum()
```

Output:

```
endTime
0.0    4
1.0    5
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Or you can also use `pd.cut`:

```
minutes = pd.cut(df['endTime'], bins=np.arange(0,df.endTime.max()+60, 60))
df['name'].ne(df['name'].shift()).groupby(minutes).sum()
```

Output:

```
endTime
(0.0, 60.0]      4
(60.0, 120.0]    5
Name: name, dtype: int64
```